# Sales Invoice report error: parameter is missing value

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have AX 2012 CU3 installed, and trying to amend the SalesInvoice report (both Data and Design) using Visual Studio 2010.

It reads the new fields added to SalesInvoiceTmp table and I can put them onto the design,

I can even build and deploy successfully. BUT : when i run the SalesInvoice report it prompts an error:

> "Parameter AgentAddress_TH" is missing value.

After investigating this issue, I realized that CU3 adds some customizations into `SalesInvoice` regarding TAX and Thai, and this particular parameter is used in a section in the report design.

I tried to make it Nullable, allow blank, hidden ... but no luck.

I didn't delete or hide any section or any textbox.

I can edit the same report on other RTM AX without any problems.

Is it a bug in CU3 that requires a hotfix or am I doing a mistake somewhere?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We are encountering something similar. There are new reports that come with CU3. Some of those changes include the addition of new parameters. This explains how to deploy these new reports: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309703.aspx .

The problem you may encounter is that this will obviously override the existing report with the default. If you have made customizations to AX reports I would make sure that you back those up. As I have made adjustments to some AX reports, the process I have taken is as follows:

1. Make sure all of my reports are backed up
2. Deploy all of the reports to the TEST/DEV environment
3. For those reports we are having issues with in PROD, download that report from the TEST/DEV report server
4. If applicable, make any formatting changes to the report
5. Upload the report to the PROD report server

Answer (score 0):

Hi. I had the same problem.

I tried to change this param's name to fx. AgentAddress_THBackup, then save, adding it to AOT, deploy, after that change the name back to AgentAddress_TH, save, adding to AOT deploy it, it works for me.

By the way, I had more than one params giving me problems, I tried to change them all at one time, it didn't work, so i did it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

i was struggling once again with this one. I did't remember how i solved it the last time, so i googled a lot and i didn't liked all provided work-arounds at all - some of them are huge in time and nerve cosumption!

So i tried a quite little work-around and it worked for me: 
1. delete the existing report on the ssrs server, with the web based report manager
2. redeploy it
3. run the report

Because that worked, I think that redeploying on existing reports can't overwrite or modify some Properties or something else, what causes this behavior.

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

1) Delete Usage Data
2) Open Development Workspace (Ctrl+D) and clear cache(s)